# How to type a recursive function that returns the intersection of 2 or more arrays of strings in Typescript?

Tags: arrays, typescript, recursion, intersection

This is the code I use to return the intersection between 2 or more arrays of string.

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wJbJsKrgIwYpwC8cAFADYboCMAXHOlFgOYDaAugDRw3oATExbtufAHRSIMABa4AMrRioAlCJitknLmQB8cAN4AoY3EQp0cKMFQBXKvHLcA3KfMAzaJSrBMZOAAGFzgMOAAefmU6CV9tORCMAGok1SMzc0ykNEwcAFs6AIEYOg4MLjdMzN94LztkABMAjwBDKnxKqrgvKB8-OAArAODBiKihWOB42TgAMlm4AEI6xpCBlLSTLq6VpvIMfMLSY-GYQQ4BioyqgF9rzIwPSl2yE807YE377Zt7RwkwHZULIKAdgAVVJ1bhk7hlHpQZPIoEp0KhJtMvlUbDA7FBkKFsLh8IRiMgKL8HDA+IjFMo0cDHjAKKpJNI5LTUZCYe44MB2sB0li-Lj8RTHJ07jcXEA)

```
export const intersection = (list1: string[], list2: string[], ...otherLists): string[] => {

  const result = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < list1.length; i++) {
      const item1 = list1[i];
      let found = false;
      for (let j = 0; j < list2.length && !found; j++) {
          found = item1 === list2[j];
      }
      if (found === true) {
          result.push(item1);
      }
  }

  if (otherLists.length) {
    return intersection(result, otherLists.shift(), ...otherLists);
  }

  else {
    return result;
  }
};
```

This works fine in JS. But now that I'm converting my code to Typescript, I would like to know how to type the `...otherLists` parameters.

I'm getting the following error:

[image]

Comment: I've updated the question. 'Cause I was missing the `return` type.

Comment: I would recommend not to write intersection by yourself. That is a common "problem" solved by the general tooling lib lodash. https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#intersection I recommend to use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how you can type it:

```
export const intersection = (list1: string[], list2: string[], ...otherLists: string[][]): string[] => {

  const result = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < list1.length; i++) {
      const item1 = list1[i];
      let found = false;
      for (let j = 0; j < list2.length && !found; j++) {
          found = item1 === list2[j];
      }
      if (found === true) {
          result.push(item1);
      }
  }

  const firstArray = otherLists.shift();
  if (firstArray) {
    return intersection(result, firstArray, ...otherLists);
  }

  return result;
};
```